# Defining Exponent in Fortran

Tags: fortran, precision, intel-fortran

I've been having some trouble with variables precision in my code...
For a while i've been declaring variables as `real(kind=8) :: var` and I now understand that this is not very portable and has some other complications, but basically I'm getting a lot of imprecision in numerical calculations.

Now I'm using:

```
INTEGER,  PARAMETER :: R8 = SELECTED_REAL_KIND (30, 300)
with variable declaration: real(R8) :: var1,var2.
```

Before I usually initialized variables as `var1 = 1.0D0` and now I'm using `var1 = 1.0_R8` but what should I do with `var1 = 1.0D-20`? I've run a simple code which proved that `1.0D-20` won't give me an accurate result but something like `10.0_r8**(-20.0_r8)` will. Is there an easier way to define the variable? I know that `1D-20` is very small but the code I'm using really needs 30 decimal case precision.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try using both: 1.0e-20_r8

Comment: not that it really matters but using `r8` for a value that's probably 16 is liable to confuse someone.

Comment: Well, `r8` being quad is really the only reason why the problem actually manifests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really two things happening here. First, declaring an exponent using `d` notation is the same as declaring it as type `double precision`.

Second, the `r8` variable you declare requires more precision than most (all?) 8-byte representations. So you're *actually* declaring most of your variables as quad, then initializing them as double, which is the source of your problem.

As mentioned in the comments, the answer to your explicit question is to declare exponents using the following notation

```
real(mytype) :: a = 1.23e-20_mytype
```

This notation is cumbersome but easy to get used to for constant declaration.

Here's a little sample code I used to test your types:

```
program main
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only : REAL64 => REAL64, REAL128
   implicit none

   INTEGER,  PARAMETER :: R8 = SELECTED_REAL_KIND (30, 300)
   real(r8) :: x, y, z
   real(REAL64) :: a, b, c

   x = 1.23d-20
   y = 1.23e-20_r8
   z = 1.23_r8*(10._r8**-20)

   write(*,*) x
   write(*,*) y
   write(*,*) z


   a = 1.23d-20
   b = 1.23e-20_REAL64
   c = 1.23_REAL64*(10._REAL64**-20)

   write(*,*) a
   write(*,*) b
   write(*,*) c

   write(*,*) 'Types: ', REAL64, R8, REAL128

end program main
```

for Intel 16.0, this gives:

```
mach5% ifort main.f90 && ./a.out
  1.230000000000000057423043720037598E-0020
  1.230000000000000000000000000000000E-0020
  1.230000000000000000000000000000002E-0020
  1.230000000000000E-020
  1.230000000000000E-020
  1.230000000000000E-020
 Types:            8          16          16
```

Comment: Good point @francescalus - I hadn't realized that `double precision` is an official part of the standard. I guess I was confusing it with `kind=8`.

Comment: Yeah, but it was unclear in the current context and the answer is better without any mention of it.